# How to expand elements in list.generate

Tags: listview, flutter, expand

I am trying to show a list of widgets (circles), yet i want to expand them and make the circles take the entire page. i tried different methods; i used flexibe, flex, and expanded. however, none of them worked. Can you please recommend? 
Thanks in advance!
 EDIT: HERE IS THE CODE:
// stepper circle is the widget i'm trying to expand between them

```
return Expanded(
  flex: 10,

    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children:
            List<Widget>.generate( numberOfCircles,
      (int index)  {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: stepperBloc.statusStream,
        initialData: {0:"incomplete", 1:"incomplete", 2:"incomplete"},
        builder:(_, AsyncSnapshot statusSnapshot){
          if(statusSnapshot.hasData){
          return   Row(
                children:<Widget>[ Flexible(
                flex:5,
                child: StepperCircle(
                index: index,
                status: statusSnapshot.data[index],
         // onTap: () => stepperBloc.statusSink({index: "selected"}),
              ),

            )],
          );
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using

Comment: done; can you please check it?

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do. Can you make a drawing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `PageView` widget, it expands each item to fill the screen (according the `viewportFraction` value) and you can set the direction vertical or horizontal.

```
        PageController controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0);

            return PageView(
              controller: controller,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ],
            );
```

More info : https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html